# How to compute the weight of s tring in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a string S, we define its weight, weight(S) as the multiplication of the positions of vowels in the string (starting from 1). Ex: weight(“e”) = 1; # weight(“age”)= 3; weight(“pippo”) = 10.

I tried this:

```
def weight(s):
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    numbers = []
    for c in s:
        if c in vowels:
                n = s.index(c)+1
                numbers.append(n)
    result = 1
    for x in numbers:
        result = result*x
    print(result)
```

But it works only with **different vowels**. If there is the same vowel in the string, the number is wrong.
What am I missing?

Thank you all.

Comment: `s.index` will find the first occurence of that vowel. You can do `for n, c in enumerate(s)` and then: `if c in vowels: numbers.append(n+1)`, without the `n = s.index(c)+1`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
s = 'pippo'
np.prod([i+1 for i,v in enumerate(s) if v in ['a','e','i','o','u']])

10
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.index()` works like `str.find` in that:

> Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found [...]
>
> Source: [str.index](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) -> [str.find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find))

only returns the *first* occurences index.

[functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [operator.mul](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul) together with [enumerate (from 1)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) makes this a one-liner:

```
from operator import  mul
from functools import reduce

value = reduce(mul, (i for i,c in enumerate("pippo",1) if c in "aeiou"))
```

Or for all your strings:

```
for t in ["e","age","pippo"]:
    # oneliner (if you omit the imports and iterating over all your given examples)
    print(t, reduce(mul, (i for i,c in enumerate(t,1) if c in "aeiou")))
```

Output:

```
e 1
age 3
pippo 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not an optimal way to do it, but this works.

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
mystring = 'pippo'
weight = 1
i = 0
while i < len(mystring):
    if mystring[i] in vowels:
        weight *= i+1
    i += 1
if weight == 1 and mystring[0] not in vowels:
    weight = 0
print(weight)
```

The final IF statement gets you rid of the ONE exceptionnal case where the string contains 0 vowels.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use enumerate. Makes the job easy

The code becomes:

```
def weight(s):
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    wt=1
    for i,c in enumerate(s):
        if c in vowels:
            wt*=i+1
    return wt

print(weight("asdew"))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying s.index(c) this returns the index of first occurence of the character in string.

You should use enumerate for iterating through the string. Enumerate gives you the value and index of the element while iterating on iterable.

```
def weight(s):
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
numbers = []
for ind, c in enumerate(s):
    if c in vowels:
            n = ind+1
            numbers.append(n)
result = 1
for x in numbers:
    result = result*x
print(result)
```

You can read about enumerate on below link :

http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html